# How to read timestamp from uint64

Tags: qt, timestamp

I want to read and display a timestamp in mseconds since epoch , which was send from a client application. My code looks like this:

```
QDateTime timestamp;

timestamp.fromMSecsSinceEpoch(dataBody.timeStamp);
out << "Time Stamp:" + timestamp.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate) + "\n";
```

However, the output is "Time Stamp:", and system says that timestamp is invalid.
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shouldn't even compile because `QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch` is a static function. Correct usage:

```
QDateTime timestamp = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(dataBody.timeStamp);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the problem, but there was no compiler error with the above code.

Comment: It is valid to call a static method with an object. Iff `Foo::m` is static, then `foo.m()` is exactly equivalent to `Foo::m()`. It could be considered a shorthand for writing out the object's type, if the object's instance is available.